# React Native testing Jest with style

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs

I have problem in React Native Jest Testing .
Jest not accept Style in React Native.

```
 FAIL  __tests__/HomeScreen-test.js
```

● Test suite failed to run

*Invariant Violation: __fbBatchedBridgeConfig is not set, cannot invoke native modules*

```
  3 | import { Colors } from './Colors';
  4 | import Fonts from '../../../assets/fonts/Fonts';
> 5 | const width = Dimensions.get('window').width;
    |                          ^
  6 | const height = Dimensions.get('window').height;
  7 | 
  8 | const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  at invariant (node_modules/invariant/invariant.js:40:15)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/NativeModules.js:169:23)
  at get (node_modules/react-native/Libraries/TurboModule/TurboModuleRegistry.js:23:24)
  at Object.getEnforcing (node_modules/react-native/Libraries/TurboModule/TurboModuleRegistry.js:38:16)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Utilities/NativeDeviceInfo.js:45:40)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Utilities/Dimensions.js:15:48)
  at Object.get Dimensions [as Dimensions] (node_modules/react-native/index.js:334:12)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/Components/Styles/HeaderMainStyles.js:5:26)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/Components/HeaderMain.js:7:48)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/Screens/HomeScreen.js:11:42)
  at Object.<anonymous> (__tests__/HomeScreen-test.js:4:42)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.68 s
Ran all test suites matching /HomeScreen-test.js/i.
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

Comment: are you adding `import 'react-native'` in the top of the test?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue?